# How to stop HTML5 video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I have a video in popup. When use below code on popup close, the video doesn't stop buffering and have the old video reference when reopen it. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="w_oPopup">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="w_cExitPopupButton"></a>
    <div id="w_oPlayer">
        <video id="w_oVideoFrame" autoplay loop controls tabindex="0" width="946" height="532" poster="">
            <source src="video.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
        </video>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.w_cExitPopupButton').bind('click', onPopupBlockerClick);

function onPopupBlockerClick(e) {
    $('#w_oPopupBlocker').hide();

    //Here my tries...
    $('#w_oVideoFrame')[0].pause();
    $('#w_oVideoFrame')[0].src = "";
}
```

Comment: Could try `$('#w_oVideoFrame').width(0).height(0);`

Comment: are you sure the selector $('#w_oVideoFrame')[0] is right?

Comment: Should be correct anand4tech

Comment: Have you tried `$('#w_oVideoFrame')[0].currentSrc = ""`?

Comment: Yes, but not working :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `pause()` method to stop the audio and set the audio path again and play. There is no `stop()` method to stop the video.

```
function stop_audio(){
    $('#w_oVideoFrame')[0].pause();
    $('#w_oVideoFrame')[0].src = " ";
}
function play_audio(){
    $('#w_oVideoFrame')[0].src = "path of audio";
    $('#w_oVideoFrame')[0].play();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use the currentTime on the selected video element

```
video.currentTime = 0;
```